# How to manually install Xamarin.Android without Xamarin account?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

As I was already developing Android apps, JDK 8 and Android SDK are already installed in my machine. But it is in a custom location, not the default one. Using the default Visual Studio installer, I could not install Xamarin without installing JDK and Android SDK again in the default location. Then I tried to install Xamarin.Android manually according to instructions in this page- 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/

This page instructed to download and install Xamarin.Android from store. But Xamarin store requires an account, which I assume to manage the paid subscriptions. Given Xamarin is free now, how should I proceed to install Xamarin.Android manually and reuse already installed Android components?

Comment: You can create the account without adding any payment information. It just needs your email id.

Comment: @AkashAmin Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can contact us at contact@xamarin.com and we will send you the latest download links to the Xamarin.VisualStudio installer which includes both Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS (there is no separate installer per platform for Windows).

The Xamarin.VisualStudio installer does not attempt to install the JDK or Android SDK, so this sounds like what you need.

Comment: I ended up creating a Xamarin account, as suggested in a comment. And then I downloaded Xamarin installer, which I think is great. It showed me that, I had JDK 8 installed, it needs JDK 7. Then it told which parts of Android SDK is not installed so needs to be installed. Previously, in the visual Studio installer, I just unchecked JDK and Android SDK, because I already have them. But that made installing Xamarin impossible. And I was confused. But the problem is solved now.